# Nested default value in a helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have the following bloc in a helm chart:

```
value: {{.Values.service.container.SubBloc.myKey |  default "mydefault"  }}
```

The default works well if in my value file I define a SubBloc but not my "mykey", like this:

```
service:
  container:
    SubBloc: 
      Key2: Value2
    resources:
      ...
```

However, if I did not define SubBloc at all, like here:

```
service:
  container:
    resources:
      ...
```

Then helm chart is not parsable.

Is there a way to parse "default nested value"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a code level, a field lookup `a.b` is valid if `a` is a dictionary (even if it doesn't contain `b`), but not if `a` is nil.  A technique I find useful here is to set a variable that should contain the parent dictionary, but uses `default` on the parent to ensure it's never nil:

```yaml
{{- $subBloc := .Values.service.container.SubBloc | default dict }}
value: {{ $subBloc.myKey |  default "mydefault" }}
```

If the upper layers could also be absent, you'd need to repeat this technique for each layer of the value tree.  It's usually safe to assume anything that's in the chart's `values.yaml` is present (though things can be explicitly overridden to be nil).  It can be helpful to design your charts to have shallower values trees to simplify this setup.